# Dynamic memory allocation to array of pointers to object

Tags: c++, pointers, object, dynamic

I have a **class** named **Student**

```
class Student
{   string name;
    unsigned long int ID ;
    string email;
    unsigned short int year;
    public : 
         Student() // Constructor
         string getName(void);
         unsigned long int getID(void);
         string getEmail(void);
         unsigned short int getYear(void);   
{
```

and another class named **eClass**

```
class eClass {
 private:
 string eclass_name;
  Student* students[100];
  unsigned int student_count;

   public:
    eClass(string name)
    {
        student_count  =0 ; 
        eclass_name = name  ; 
    }

        bool exists(Student obj)
    {
        unsigned long int code = obj.getID();
        bool flag = TRUE ;
        for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i<=student_count ; i++ )
        {
            unsigned long int st = (*students[i]).getID();
            if (code==st)
            {
                flag = FALSE;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }


        void add(Student& obj)
    { 
        bool res = exists(obj);
        if (res)
        {
            students[student_count] = new Student(); //probably the problem is here
            *students[student_count] = obj ;  
            student_count++ ; 
        }
    }

    string getEclassName(void) { return eclass_name; }
    unsigned int getStudentCount(void) { return student_count; }
    Student getStudent(int i) { return *students[i-1]; }


     };
```

The statement **Student* students[100];** must look exactly like this . For example I can't write something like this: Student* students[100]={} ;

And main() looks like this

```
    int main()
   {
     Student    JohnDoe("John Doe", 12345,  2,  "johndoe@gmail.gr");
     eClass Cpp("C++"); 
     Cpp.add(JohnDoe);


     }
```

Basically I have an array of pointers to Student objects and I want to allocate dynamically memory every time I want to add a new Student object.

When I compile I get no errors but when I try to run the program the only thing I get is "Program_name.exe" stopped running...

I'm pretty sure the problem has to do with memory allocation but I'm not able to find it and solve it.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: from what I can see, the code above looks fine; can you post the implementation of `Student`?

Comment: Why are you using pointers to `Student`s? Just store `Student`s.

Comment: From what you posted, I estimate the major bug is in `exists(Student obj)`.  Anyway, you shouldn't be passing by value into that function (but I don't think **that** is the major bug).  Add your implementation of `exists` to you post.

Comment: The prime suspect is `exists`. (Side note: `exists` returning `true` if the student *doesn't* exist is very counter-intuitive.)

Comment: I edited and added the Student class and the exist function... Using pointers isn't my choice...Our professor asked us to do it this way

Comment: The line you commented as suspect `students[student_count] = new Student();` look fine.  It would be cleaner to do `students[student_count] = new Student(obj);` and get rid of the following line.  But that is no likely to be the problem you're looking for now.

Comment: Something is missing for the constructor (maybe just a `;`) so the `Student` class you posted is not what you compiled.

Comment: As expected, you use an uninitialized pointer inside `exists` in the code `(*students[i]).getID()`  You don't want `=` in `i<=student_count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main bug in `exists` was the loop went one too far, using an uninitialized pointer.  But also it is very bad style for `exists` to take its input by value.  Fixing both of those:

```
bool exists(Student const& obj)
{
    unsigned long int code = obj.getID();
    bool flag = TRUE ;
    for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i<student_count ; i++ )
    {
        unsigned long int st = (*students[i]).getID();
        if (code==st)
        {
            flag = FALSE;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

You should declare `getID()` const inside student in order to be able to code `exists` correctly.

```
unsigned long int getID() const;
```

Comment: Wow...thanks a lot my friend...I never imagined that one more loop would create such a big problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should initialize all of your student pointers to either NULL or nullprt.  This is not strictly needed but is a very good habit to get into.  You'll thank yourself later.

Second, why are you returning false if the student exists?  Kind of confusing I'd imagine.  Also, you can use the `break` statement after you find your student exists; no need to check the rest of them.

Also, on your add, you may want to check to ensure you don't have MORE than 100 students.  This will overwrite memory and bad things will happen.

Comment: Notice the use of `student_count` to control the use of `students`.  So if `student_count` were used correctly, there is no need to initialize `students` and when `student_count` was used incorrectly, initializing `students` would not have helped.

Comment: @JSF Added an explanation on that one.  I know it isn't NEEDED but it is a good habit to get into this early on.  Always initialize EVERYTHING; pointers, ints, classes, conversation, etc ....

Comment: I wouldn't have commented if your second sentence had been there when I commented.  **BUT** the word "need" in the first sentence is still wrong (contradicted by the second).  "ought to" or "should" would cover it.

Comment: I was changing that as you commented.  I thought I'd removed that first need.  Let me get that.